# how to integration test wcf Service Reference client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, integration-testing, service-reference

We are exposing an wcf SDK of our apps via an asp.net mvc route as seen in the RouteConfig below.  We also utilize a Service Reference client project for our apps to call the SDKs of our other apps.

Is there a way to host the SDKService in a Visual Studio Test Assembly/Class so that we can write tests the verify communication between the Service Reference client and SDKService?

The dependencies of the SDKService are all interfaces that can be supplied with mocks. SDKService itself is covered with tests.

If this is a duplicate question, I apologize. Every post I've read through here and around the web all say "There isn't ANY value in testing the client, because you are just testing CONFIGURATION."  That's all well and good, however, if one adds, removes, or changes a property on one of the models passed to or returned by SDKService the Service Reference needs to be updated.

We'd like to be able to have tests in place that will prevent us from committing changes to code associated with SDKService without updating its dependent Service Reference. Thus, we'd like to be able to test the communication between the Service and Service Reference.

Thank you for any thoughts or ideas that may lead to a solution.

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        if (AppSettings.EnableIntegration)
            routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("sdk", new IntegrationHostFactory()
            {
                BindingConfigurationName = "sdkInName",
                ServiceContractType = typeof(ISdk),
                ErrorHandler = new ExceptionHandler(),
                HttpConfig = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            }, typeof(SDKService)));
        );
    }
}
```

Service Contract

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISdk
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetIceCream();

    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<string> GetFlavors();
}
```

Implementation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, 
 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class SDKService : ISdk
{
    public string GetIceCream(string id)
    {
        return "Moose Tracks";
    }

    IEnumerable<string> GetFlavors()
    {
        return new List<string> { "Moose Tracks", "Chocolate Chip",
            "Vanilla", "Black Jack Cherry" };
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="IceCream.Application.SDKService" />
</services>
<bindings configSource="configuration\WCF-Bindings.config" />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                           multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" 
                  logMalformedMessages="false" logKnownPii="false" 
                   logEntireMessage="false" />
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Sounds like what you want to do is write an application that consumes your service, and calls every method to make sure that things that work continue to work. The application could very well be a standalone Test Project that is executed from a unit test environment.

Comment: We have a standalone Test Project with the purpose of writing tests that exercise the communication between the SDKService and our SDK.Client project that contains the Service Reference.  The question we are trying to solve is how to host the SDKService in the test environment, such that our tests which call the methods on our SDK.Client can call through to the SDKService.